# I wanted to know how to load contents dynamically in slide panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to load contents dynamically into the slide panel?

For example, I want to load content on the news when the slide panel toggled and when scrolled down, the contents should be loaded dynamically.

An example of slide panel is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xpp5sgg8/2/. So when the panel is toggled the contents should be displayed.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass("sidebar-collapsed");
});
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar, .toggle {
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar {
    background:lightgrey;
    width:200px;
    height:100vh;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.toggle {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:black;
}

.sidebar-collapsed {
     transform:translateX(-100%);   
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
}

.sidebar-collapsed .toggle {
    right:-5px;
     transform:translateX(100%);   
    -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);   
}
```

Comment: You can use AJAX to dynamically load content in to your site. If you search there are a lot of questions already covering how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing [mcve]s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Slider on ajax loaded content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885655/load-slider-on-ajax-loaded-content)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small example for your code. It preloads img and appends it to your `.sidebar`

http://jsfiddle.net/xpp5sgg8/171/

If you are using **jQuery**, have a look at [**jQuery.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation.